# Why am I getting "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int" error when I use a date type variable instead of hard coded date?

Tags: sql-server, date, sqldatatypes

I'm a bit confused as to why am I getting "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int" error when I use a date variable instead of a hardcoded date in the condition mentioned for WHILE loop.

```
Declare @ddate date='2013-03-25', @MembershipDate date= '2013-03-27',@id int=0
while (@ddate<=DATEADD(mm,3,@MembershipDate)-1) 
begin
set @id=@id+1
end
```

But if I use the hardcoded date directly as mentioned below then I don't get any error

```
Declare @ddate date='2013-03-25',@id int=0
while (@ddate<=DATEADD(mm,3,'2013-03-27')-1) 
begin
set @id=@id+1
end
```

Please let me know the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you use a string this is implictly cast to datetime and the result of `DATEADD` is datetime.

When you use a date the result of `DATEADD` is date.

this is specified in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-types)

> `DATEADD (datepart , number , date )`
>
> The `date` argument data type becomes the DATEADD return value data
>   type, except for string literal date values. For a string literal,
>   DATEADD returns a datetime value.

The newer date and time datatypes don't support this type of arithmetic. You can use `DATEADD` with `day` and `-1` to subtract a day from those. This is clearer anyway.

Comment: Thanks. There is no error when GETDATE() function is used in place of hardcoded date so does that mean that the return type of GETDATE() function is string? And how can I use DATEADD with day and -1, my objective is to find the date 3 months ahead with 1 day less.

Comment: No the return type of GETDATE is DATETIME as well. This is a legacy datatype that behaves differently from the newer ones such as DATE and DATETIME2. You just need to wrap your original DATEADD expression in another DATEADD to subtract the day

Comment: Martin, could you please mention the exact statement/code for "wrap your original DATEADD expression in another DATEADD to subtract the day"

Comment: @user `DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,3,@MembershipDate))`